# Post Video content and thumbnail on Twitter

Tags: android

I have integrate Twitter in my app successfully. But i couldn't post contents on my twitter account wall. I have tried many examples and tutorial. Please help me about this problem. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I have tried tutorial Twitter Integration in your Android Application and follow the sample project Github-AndroidTwitterSample Repository best and followed it. But there is problem with me that i am not getting callback on my app. There are 4 tabs in my app. i want to back in my app and post contents on twitter wall. If u can help i will highly thankfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I use Twitter4j library which you can download at http://twitter4j.org and add to your libs folder in your project.

For the callback url, you have to set it up in your AndroidManifest like so :

```
         <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="callback-url" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

After you get your access token back, I would do the following to tweet a file :

```
public void tweet(File f, String Message)
            throws TwitterException {

            StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(Message);
            status.setMedia(f);
            // twitter is an object of Twitter for which you have set the authentication token
            twitter.updateStatus(status);
    }
```

This works well for images but I haven't tried it with video but it seems to me that it would work, you have to try it though.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Please help me more about to post thumbnail also on twitter via same way. I will heartly thankfull to you.

Comment: You could use the same method to post an image as well. the File in that case be the image not the video.

Comment: Can u please some elaborate about what are you actually saying ? Any example will be more helpfull.